# Is there a way to get the Stack Exchange platform?

Tags: discussion, stack-exchange

I am looking for a way to integrate Q and A into my website, and I love Stack Exchange. Is there a way to integrate something like it onto my website?

Answer (score 2):

Stack Exchange is closed source. You can always start a topic over at [Area 51](http://area51.stackexchange.com/) if you wish. But if you are looking for something you can host, there's a list of clones take a look at [Stack Exchange clones](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2267/stack-overflow-clones)